# Probability: Card distribution problem

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, card-games

1. A deck of 52 cards is equally dealt to 4 players.

Find the number of ways to distribute the cards so that each player has exactly one card from each rank.

[Note: A deck of 52 cards consists of 13 ranks, A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, each has four suits

2. A deck of 52 cards is equally dealt to 4 players.

Find the number of ways to distribute the cards so that the cards for each player are of the same colour.

[Note: in a deck of 52 cards, 26 of them are red and 26 of them are black]

Edit: I am so sorry, I am new to this environment and it is so ignorant of me to do that without sharing my thought.

For first question, what I can think now:

(4C1 × 3C1 × 2C1 × 1C1)^13 = (4!)^13
What I think is from each rank, first person take one, second person take one, and so on till last person. Then I power it to 13 since there are 13 ranks.

For second question, what I can think now:

(26C13 × 4C1 × 13C13 × 3C1 × 26C13 × 2C1 × 13C13 × 1C1)
What I think is the deck divided to two groups, red and black. Then we distribute the red to the first person and second person, then black to tge rest of the group.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: what if you had a deck with just aces? Just aces and $2$s? Can you see what the pattern will be?

Comment: You have posed $2$ questions in one post. At least show whatever efforts you have made, even if they have proved abortive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Distribution of the cards among four hands such that each receives one card from each rank.

> (4C1 × 3C1 × 2C1 × 1C1)^13 = (4!)^13 What I think is from each rank, first person take one, second person take one, and so on till last person. Then I power it to 13 since there are 13 ranks.

**Yes.** The four suits from each of the thirteen ranks may be distributed in $4!$ ways, so the total count is $4!^{13}$ ways.

2. Distribute the cards among the four hands such that each is comprised of one from the two colours.

> 26C13 × 4C1 × 13C13 × 3C1 × 26C13 × 2C1 × 13C13 × 1C1

**Almost.**  There are $^{4}\mathcal C_2$ ways to select two hands to receive black cards, $^{26}\mathcal C_{13}$ ways to distribute those twenty-six cards among those two hands, and likewise $^{26}\mathcal C_{13}$ ways to distribute the red cards among the remaining two hands.$${^{4}\mathcal C_{2}}{^{26}\mathcal C_{13}}{^{26}\mathcal C_{13}} =\dfrac{4!~26!^2}{2!^2~13!^4}$$

*Modifying your method:*  Select a hand to receive the Ace of Spades and twelve other black cards, select a second hand to receive the remaining thirteen black cards, repeat with the Ace of Hearts and the remaining twenty-five red cards.

$${^{4}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{25}\mathcal C_{12}}{^{3}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{13}\mathcal C_{13}}~{^{2}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{25}\mathcal C_{12}}{^{1}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{13}\mathcal C_{13}}$$

**Note:** ${^{4}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{3}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{2}\mathcal C_{1}}= 4\times{^{4}\mathcal C_{2}}$ and $2\times{^{25}\mathcal C_{12}} = {^{26}\mathcal C_{13}}$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I would like to ask about something.

Why it is not:
Red: 26C13 x 4C2 x 2! --> 2! as among those two selected there are two options, give the first half to A or first half to B, and so do the B

And finally, in total: 2 x (26C13 x 4C2 x 2!) possibilities

Comment: Yes.  How did that ...?

Comment: @Confuse.  How do you define "first half" and "second half"?  I defined it as: "the half with the $A\heartsuit$" and "the half without".   So: you select 1 from 2 people, select the ace of hearts and 12 from 25 red cards, select the remaining person, and select the remaining 13 red cards.$${{^{2}\mathcal C_{1}}{^{25}\mathcal C_{12}}{^{1}\mathcal C_{1}{^{13}\mathcal C_{13}}} \\= \dfrac{2!~25!~1!~13!}{1!1!~12!13!~1!1!~13!0!}\\=\dfrac{2\cdot 13\cdot 25!}{13\cdot 12!~13!}\\={^{26}\mathcal C_{13}}}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I just divided it randomly 13 red and another 13 red as I don't think the A rank necessarily need to be divided into two different groups. Like it is possible for a person to have A heart and A diamonds at the same time

Comment: Yes, but only one from the two hands may have the Ace of Hearts.  So you select which of the players receives this card, along with any 12 from the remaining 25 red cards, and assign the remaining 13 red cards to the final player.  This is how you partition the twenty six red cards between the two players.